# Number of items in a single row in a flexbox

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox container with several items in it. They have been row-wrapped. Is there a way, using JavaScript, to get the number of items in each row? (in other words, what was the breakpoint for wrapping?)

For example-

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

Now, there could either 1 or 2 or 3 ... or all 6 `items` in the first row.
Is there any way, I could find out how many `items` are there in the first row and the subsequent rows?

One possible solution is that: If I had the width of the `items` to be fixed then I could have just got that number by `screen_width/width_of_item`. But currently, I have the size of `items` change according to the viewport (like it's `400px` for desktop and `600px` for mobiles, etc). This media-queries make this solution a little messy (but nonetheless, this solution works provided all the items had the same width).

But is there a cleaner way of doing the same?
(What if each item had its own custom width?!)

**Edit:** Why am I looking for this info?

Currently, I am working on my [startpage](https://github.com/kishlaya/Tiles/). I want to improve keyboard navigation. Here's the problem with it: When I press down arrow, I want to mark the tile below the current one to be active. Getting this `below' tile is the problem at hand.

On line 389 of `keys.js`, I have `-4`, which works for desktop screens but this value needs to be changed to `-2` for mobile screens and similarly for other different viewports.

Comment: Why are you looking for that information?

Comment: Loop over all items and either add up their actual calculated widths while doing so - or have a look at what their top offset is. When that changes between one item and the next, that would mean the next is on a new “line” …

Comment: There's no direct method, but I would use each element's `offsetTop` for example if all elements in a row are aligned to the top.

Comment: @Vlad274 I have answered your question as an edit in my original question. Please let me know if it makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Keyboard navigation is also tied into AODA(accessibility), I wouldn't mess with the up/down arrows, using tab should goto each element as the default way. You would also need tabindex if you want to navigate it naturally.

Comment: Does `container` only contain 1 row at a time?

Comment: @Huangism Yes, if I were to do it from scratch I would have used tabindex instead. But someone had already done it and it was kinda nice for a startpage (I wanted my startpage to be fancy).

Comment: @Huangism Yes, it only has a single row because this way I was able to achieve more flexibility (no pun intended), compared to using tables or bootstrap's grid layout

Comment: @kishlaya if `container` only contain 1 row at a time then it is really easy to get the number of items in a row/container https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll then you just `.length` and you have your number of items

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193097/discussion-between-kishlaya-and-huangism).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.getComputedStyle(item)` to get the width of each item. Then easily calculate `screen_width / width_of_item`.